# Quasi-disjoint subsets of an infinite set and $\neg \mathsf{AC}$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (without $\mathsf{AC}$) that there is an infinite set $X$ and a subset $S\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ of the same cardinality as $\mathcal P(X)$ with the property that whenever $s\neq t\in S$ we have $|s\cap t| \leq 1$?

Note that it is consistent that there is such a pair of sets $X,S$, with $|S|>|X|$, but no such $X$ can be well-orderable. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1173404/462) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243544/462).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth pointing out that it is definitely consistent that $|X|<|S|$. Is "cset" a typo?

Comment: The statement is clearly false when $S$ is finite (or empty), and you haven't imposed any requirement preventing that. So could you clarify the precise statement about which you are asking? It doesn't make sense to ask for consistency when $X$ and $S$ are already-fixed parameters, so I imagine you have in mind a statement quantifying over $X$ and $S$. The statement is also false when $S$ simply consists of all the singleton sets. Perhaps you are asking whether it is consistent that there is any instance of this at all?

Comment: Hi Joel, Yes, the statement being asked is whether it is consistent to have any instances of this situation.

Comment: In that case, the question should be edited. To start out by saying, "Let $X$ be an infinite set..." suggests that one has a universal quantifier, but really the question is:  Is it consistent with ZF that there is a set $X$ and a collection $S$, such that...?

Comment: More clearly:  is it consistent with ZF that there is an infinite set $X$ and an injection $f:P(X)\to P(X)$ such that $|f(A)\cap f(B)|\leq 1$ whenever $A\neq B$?

Comment: I have edited the question slightly based on the comments.

Comment: In the second paragraph, you say "such a pair of sets", but I think you no longer intend here that $S$ has the same size as $P(X)$, which was one of the properties in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Joel Yes, you are right. Would you mind retouching the question, please?

Comment: Thanks Joel & Andres for making the question much clearer & better!

Comment: As a weaker version of your question, is it consistent that there exist an infinite set $X$ and a surjection from $X\times X$ to $\mathcal P(X)$?

Comment: Very interesting, @bof, I suggest you put this as a new question on MO

Comment: @bof: No, this is impossible. You can find this in Jech's The Axiom of Choice, if I remember correctly. If $|X|>5$ then, $2^{|X|}>|X|^2$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well then, that answers Dominic van der Zypen's question, doesn't it? If $S$ is a "quasi-disjoint" (as defined here) family of subsets of $X$, then there is a surjection from $X\times X$ to $S$, right?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: This choiceless stuff always confuses me. Does $|A|\lt|B|$ imply that there is no surjection from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: @bof: You're right, it doesn't imply there is no surjection. I think this particular question is still open, if it's even possible to have such surjection. I don't see how there is a surjection from $X^2$ onto $S$ under the assumptions in the question, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Let $A=\mathbb R$ and $B=\mathbb R\cup\omega_1$. There is a surjection from $A$ to $B$ but it's consistent that $|A|\lt|B|$.

Comment: @bof: Yes, that is a classical example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Choose $a,b\in X,\ a\ne b.$ Define $f:X\times X\to S$ as follows. Let $f(x,x)=\{x\}.$ Let $f(a,b)=\emptyset.$ If $x\ne y$ and $(x,y)\ne(a,b),$ let $f(x,y)$ be the **unique** member of $S$ containing $\{x,y\}$ if there is one, otherwise let $f(x,y)=\emptyset.$ The range of $f$ is a superset of $S$.

Comment: I believe I've seen *quasidisjoint family* used as a synonym for $\Delta$-system, i.e., a family of sets in which each pair has the same intersection.

Comment: @bof: Ah, yes. In any case, yes this is what I had in mind last night when I first laid eyes on this question. Some $\Delta$-system or some coloring argument (color each pair in $S$ by the intersection, if you can find a homogeneous set of size $|S|$ we can derive a contradiction). But those, of course, require choice in the general case.